# 3d Max, maxScript. Set vertex position

Tags: vertex, 3dsmax, maxscript

How to set vertex position in 3d Max in maxScript?

```
$.selectedVerts.pos.x = 10 - not working
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple ways, first for some collections the mapped property assignment doesn't work, you have to iterate over them:

```
for vert in $.selectedVerts do vert.pos.x = 10
```

There are also methods appropriate for the given object class, i.e.:

```
meshOp.setVert <Mesh mesh> <vertlist> <point3 pos>
polyOp.setVert <Poly poly> <vertlist> <point3 pos>
```

So for example for Editable Poly:

```
(
    fn getPlanarPos obj vert dist axis:#x =
    (
        local pos = polyOp.getVert obj vert
        setProperty pos axis dist
        pos
    )

    local obj = selection[1]
    local distX = 10

    local verts = polyOp.getVertSelection obj
    local vertsPos = for vert in verts collect getPlanarPos obj vert distX
    polyOp.setVert obj #selection vertsPos
)
```

This is quite a bit more verbose but it won't trigger an update/viewport redraw (compare to an update with each iteration of the `vert.pos.x` assignment), here you are even setting all the verts in one go (if you want to see the result immediately, add `update obj` at the end).